# CUDA occupancy table for Maxwell architecture and compute capability 5

Tags: cuda

I am trying to use cuda occupancy calculator for a Maxwell GPU that caters compute capability of 5. Unfortunately, the occupancy table in the select compute capability option allows until 3.5.

Do you know where can I find an update version or what i can do to calculate for compute capability 5?

Thanks

Comment: The CUDA Occupancy Calculator shipped with CUDA 7 is ready for CC 5.x.

Comment: @pQB if you want to make that an answer I would upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA Occupancy Calculator shipped with CUDA 7 is ready for CC 5.x.

Comment: For instance, on a standard CUDA linux install, it is at `/usr/local/cuda/tools`